# What is the use of the soft sign in front of (soft-indicating) vowels, in words like "компьютеры" and "пьёт"?

Tags: орфография

I was told that the soft sign makes the preceding consonant soft. I understand why it used at the end of words (царь, гулять, здесь) or before consonants (огоньки, письмо). But why is the soft sign used between a consonant and a soft-indicating vowel (like ю and ё) in words like "ком**пью**теры" and "**пьё**т"? Wouldn't the consonant before the soft sign already be pronounced soft because of the soft-indicating vowel coming after it?

I read it has something to do with "[iotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotation)", but I couldn't figure out what that means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A soft or hard sign before a vowel indicates the palatal approximant *[j]*. This is the first sound in the English word "year" which makes it distinct from "ear".

Russian words [*лёд*](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B4/#ru) "ice" and [*льёт*](http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%82/#ru) "(he) pours" are pronounced *[lʲɵt]* and *[lʲjɵt]*, appropriately. They only differ in that one sound.

Hard sign in modern Russian is only used on morpheme boundaries, separating the roots starting with *е, ё, ю, я* from some preceding morphemes ending in a hard consonant; and, sometimes, in transcriptions.

Usage of a hard versus soft sign is, hence, etymological rather than phonetical. Techically, one is supposed to pronounce a palatalized (soft) consonant before a soft sign and non-palatalized (hard) before a hard sign, however, in practice, many Russian speakers soften consonants preceding *[j]* even if it's denoted by a hard sign. Most Russian speakers would pronounce the first consonant in *адъютант* and *адью* exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

After soft and hard sign and after other vowels, vowels е, ё, ю, я are iotized and read [й'э], [й'о], [й'у], [й'а] respectively.